# Crystal Reports keeps giving me: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, .net-assembly

So I have a C# website that I have to work with. It uses crystal reports so I installed it (First time working with crystal reports). I came across the following error while trying to run the website

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=11.5.9.1229, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

These are the logs :

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=11.5.9.1229, Culture=neutral,        PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/School/Vacaturesite/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\School\Vacaturesite\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\School\Vacaturesite\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Beheerder\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=11.5.9.1229,   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Beheerder/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary   ASP.NET Files/vs/ae77f9fe/8f0f70a0/CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Beheerder/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary   ASP.NET      Files/vs/ae77f9fe/8f0f70a0/CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework/CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL   file:///C:/School/Vacaturesite/bin/CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I've tried various things and searched the internet for answers but so far nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install crystal reports runtime. Follow the below thread to download http://scn.sap.com/thread/2071900

Following is more detailed list where you will get all runtime versions
 http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com&pageId=56787567

Comment: yes, the referenced assemblies will be picked from GAC. You need to make sure that you are installing the right version of Crystal Runtime. Please check the updated post.